# Kill all processes running on port 8080 on Mavericks

Tags: terminal, port, osx-mavericks, kill

I'm getting a "`socket.error: No socket could be created`" when running a web.py script.

Is there a way to kill all processes on running on port 8080 (or any other port I wish) with a single line in Terminal on OSX Mavericks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a single line, but you'd need to put it into a shell alias or shell script in order to make it easy to use:

```
$ kill $(lsof -i tcp:8080 | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

If you want to see and kill processes that don't belong to you, then `sudo` needs to get involved:

```
$ sudo kill $(sudo lsof -i tcp:8080 | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: Thank you @Droppy! Works great. I used sudo.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to kill all proccesses running on port 8080 in ubuntu is:

> sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp